# Unity - Translate a GameObject 3d Cube Edge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, cube

I use a C# script to populate my scene with a couple of cubes, then pick a certain number of them and transform them.
The transformation I want to do is as per [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1utA.png)

How do I move an edge of a basic Unity 3d Object Cube (in C# script)?

Comment: not possible as far as I know.

Comment: So, I would have to create my own 3d cube instead of the basic one, and implement that kind of transformation for myself?

Comment: you want that transformation at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by editing the vertices of the Mesh. For example, attach this script to a cube and adjust the camera so you can see things shift around as you hit the space bar. You should see the box shift and get an idea how to get what you want.

```
public class CubeScript : MonoBehaviour {

int vert_num = 0;
Mesh mesh;
Vector3[] verts;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    verts = mesh.vertices;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {

        // Loop back around after the last vert
        if (vert_num >= verts.Length) {
            vert_num = 0;
        }

        // Move the next vert and echo its number
        Debug.Log("Moving vert#: " + vert_num);
        verts[vert_num] += Vector3.up * 0.1f;
        mesh.vertices = verts;

        vert_num += 1;
    }
}
```

}

For more info see: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

Comment: Ok, it make sense. So I draw a bunch of cube, then pick the one I want to incline and get its mesh and verts. Now, I lower 2 vertices, but do I also ned to modify the Edges or Faces in order to make a correct shape once again?

Comment: You should just need to lower 6 verts. The top 2 for the right panel and the right 2 for the top panel, the top right for the front panel, the top right for the back panel. Depending on your shaders and how you're using the object you may need to call RecalculateNormals() on the mesh when you're done.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that it might be less CPU expensive to just have 2 fixed meshes and an animation. Depends on how many objects you plan to have in the scene and how many types of transformations you plan to use.